# Calling Json script and displaying the Images within the script

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to access a Json script, it is in a domain. The script holds a couple of images, which are hyperlinked. I've tried using WWW to access the script, but the image i received was a picture of a huge red question mark. Clearly I'm going about the wrong way with this. So i'm assuming I'm supposed to decode the json script through unity and then display the image with the ability to see next/previous image by clicking? I'm unfamiliar with Json so how about would i call the script and read the the images it's calling?

This is what my code looks like, the code works since I've tried another non Json domain with just an image- and it works perfectly fine.

```
 void Start ()

{   
    renderer.material.mainTexture = new Texture2D(4,4, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
    url = "http://hosting.xivmedia.com/JsonHome/JSON/more_games.json";

        www = new WWW(url);
        StartCoroutine(WaitForSeconds(www));
}

IEnumerator WaitForSeconds(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;
    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(renderer.material.mainTexture as Texture2D);

    if (www.error == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.data);
        imageLoaded = true;

    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);
    } 
}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(20, 80, 100, 100),     renderer.material.mainTexture as Texture2D,  ScaleMode.StretchToFill);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you said correctly, you'll need to decode the JSON script first. You'll need a JSON parser to do that. The one I highly recommend is [JSON .NET For Unity](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/11347), but [MiniJSON](https://gist.github.com/darktable/1411710) should do just fine.

So, assuming your json is just a list of URLs as so:

```
[  
    "http://.....",  
    "http://....."   
]
```

With JSON.NET you would modify your code as follows:

```
IEnumerator WaitForSeconds(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;

    string json = www.text;
    List<string> imageUrls = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<string>>(json);
    foreach (string imageUrl in imageUrls)
    {
        WWW imageWWW = new WWW(imageUrl);
        imageWWW.LoadImageIntoTexture(renderer.material.mainTexture as Texture2D);

        if (imageWWW .error == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + imageWWW.data);
            imageLoaded = true;

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + imageWWW.error);
        } 
    }
}
```

If the JSON is more complicated, you can create a class that the JSON can deserialize to. I.e., if the JSON is a list of objects as so:

```
[
    {
        "name": "test",
        "url" : "http://...."
    },
    {
        "name": "something",
        "url" : "http://..."
    }
]
```

Then you would have a simple class

```
public class ImageData
{
    public string name;
    public string url;
}
```

And deserialize the JSON as so

```
List<ImageData> imageUrls = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<ImageData>>(json);
foreach (ImageData data in imageUrls)
{
    WWW imageWWW = new WWW(data.url);
    imageWWW.LoadImageIntoTexture(renderer.material.mainTexture as Texture2D);
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough reply Pek, helped me a great deal. Just a quick question, how would I go about keeping my code Dynamic? I'm planning on adding more images( which take you to a link when clicked) and I need it to take effect when the game is up and running. Also, thank you a great deal Pek. I've also opted to use MiniJson, but I'm having issues with deserializing the images- following how you have layed it out with the other plugin. Can you aid me in understanding how the code would be layed out using MiniJSon. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, glad I helped. Unfortunately, I have not used MiniJson to help you more. As for your code being Dynamic, I'm afraid that is a very general question. I would suggest maybe create a new question and provide more information. I'm sure you'll get a lot of responses.